# cisco parse show command

Tags: cisco

I want to write a perl script which logs into cisco switches via telnet and parses the output of `show mac-address-table`. The problem is that different switches show me a different field layout.

The WS-C3548-XL shows the fields in the order

`Destination Address  Address Type  VLAN  Destination Port`

while the C2960 shows it like

`Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports`

is there a way to tell show to print the fields in a predefined order?

Comment: You can handle this in your script by checking the output header.

Comment: Have a look at how [NeDi](http://www.nedi.ch) does this.

Comment: telnet [shivers], I don't understand why this prehistoric, clear text protocol is still supported on these devices. Can't you use ssh instead?

Comment: Parsing the output is doing it wrong.  Use SNMP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poll the devices using SNMP.
I would think the MIBs are the same but you never know with Cisco.

Comment: yes, i solved it now via snmp. i only tried the telnet approach because i couldn't find the right oids, but it finally seems to work with RFC1286-MIB

Answer (score 0):

No, not that I know of.

But since you're already using perl, just check the first line. From there on, you know what the meanings of the particular fields are, and fill your hash (I hope you're using one!) accordingly. This has the additional advantage that in the future, you can support other models with yet another output format. While still supporting the "old" ones. Robust programming.

...Oh, and make sure to handle the space in "Address Type" :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of scripting using SNMP
You can run external snmpget / snmpwalk utilities and parse the output or use the Net::SNMP module.

Answer (score 0):

SNMP would be best.  But also remember that the "include" output modifier is regex capable.  You could just grab the info you want if you want stick with Perl-expect